# Warning: Could not find file NetBeans 6.0 M9\enterprise4\modules\ext\standard.jar to copy

Tags: jsp, servlets, netbeans

reading on web application servlet & jsp right now and the book(2008) ask to import this program and run it to make sure everything is installed and configured successfully. I only tested a few projects from the same downloaded folder and they all worked except this one (which might be the only one using MySQL). Wondering if anyone knows this error?

> > C:\murach\servlet_jsp\netbeans\book_apps\musicStore\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1006: Warning: Could not find file C:\murach\Program Files\NetBeans 6.0 M9\enterprise4\modules\ext\standard.jar to copy.
> >     BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

I'm guessing I have to go and download this stardard.jar and put it in this directory? but I don't have this directory and I'm using NetBeans 8.0. or it just means I don't have MySQL set up right.

Comment: If you are using Netbeans 8.0, and the imported project insists on loading a Netbeans 6.0 file, I would say something smells around ... Anyway, you should at least give the URL for the project having problems !

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you mean. But here's where I downloaded the project files: http://murach.com/books/jsp2/download.htm

Comment: try `clean and build` whole project and then `deploy` this might solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this same problem, and though I couldn't resolve it using the files from 2nd ed. ZIP (jsp2), I downloaded the 3rd ed. files from:  http://murach.com/downloads/jsp3.htm

Using the musicStore project from this ZIP worked using the same instructions with NetBeans 8.